# How to store the different timers in a dict or array in a plist to load each view

Tags: iphone

I want to store the times to switch for each view in a dict or array in a plist. How i can do this. Thanks for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot serialize NSTimer to plist, because NSTimer don't support NSCoding protocol.
You can store in NSArray collection of NSDictionary'es with keys:

- selector
- time interval
- user info

Selector can be NSString, you can convert it to SEL using NSSelectorFromString:

`SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(@"method:");`

In this case you can create timers from dictionary:

```
NSArray* timers = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"timers.plist"];
id target; // you cannot store target in plist, you must use one target for all timers

for ( NSDictionary* dict in timers )
{
    NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[[dict objectForKey:@"interval"] intValue] target:target selector:NSSelectorFromString([dict objectForKey:@"selector"]) userInfo:[dict objectForKey:@"userinfo"] repeats:NO];
}
```